# What is the difference between a $p$-group and a Sylow group?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

We have just started a course about Group theory. I am confused about the difference between a $p$-group and a Sylow group.

As I understand it, a group $G$ is called $p$-group if $|G|=p^{m}$, where $p$ is a prime and $0\leq m$.

However, I am not sure what a Sylow group is. I know that there are theorems called sylow theorems that determine the properties of sylow groups, but is there a clear definition of a sylow group and is there a clear difference between sylow group and $p$-group.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Sylow group. They are called Sylow subgroups, and surely your book will have a definition of the term.

Comment: The word "sub". Sylow *sub*group.

Comment: The Sylow ones have to have the maximum value of $m$ (possible for that $p$). So a group order 72 has Sylow subgroups order 8 and 9.

Comment: @almagest, So every Sylow subgroup is a $p$-group, is that right?

Comment: Yes, but not every $p$-subgroup is a Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite $p$-*group* is a group whose order is a power of $p$.

(More generally, a $p$-group is a group in which each element has order a power of $p$.)

A Sylow *subgroup* of a group $G$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Every Sylow subgroup is a $p$-group for some $p$.

Not every $p$-subgroup of a group is a Sylow subgroup.
For instance, $C_2 \times 1$ is not a Sylow subgroup of $C_2 \times C_4$.

Comment: Though any $p$-group is a Sylow subgroup of some group (e.g. itself).